# MSB first radix sort

Tags: sorting

As given in books radix sort is generally done from LSB to MSB . But i think by using MSB to LSB we can divide input elements into smaller partitions.. Now I have to construct an example to show that MSB first radix sort can be asymptotically worse than LSB first radix sort.. This is my assignment problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get a good response here, you should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Let the range of sorting be [1, n2], i.e. we need two applications of bucket sorting in the range [1, n]. If we use MSB first sorting, then the time bound is ∑(i=1 to n)  O(ni +n), where ni is the number of elements in the bucket (of the MSB). The range is [1, n] for the LSB. 
Also sorting m numbers in the range [1, n] takes time O(m + n).
The value of ∑(i=1 to n)  O(ni +n) = n + ∑(i=1 to n)  n can be Ω(n2).

Answer (score 0):

Radix sort is not as limited as first appearances might suggest. It's now the heart of a lot of GPGPU sorts (hurrah! bitonic sort goes back in the closet). I wrote up the basic way to make radix sort practical for many datasets where the keys can be ordered by memcmp(3) in this [google doc on radix sort](http://goo.gl/eZeqJI) --- copying the diagrams into stackoverflow text boxes is beyond me :-) The one big "hurdle" is to not follow the "divide and conquer" approach of quicksort, since it repeats the expensive start-up cost of MSB radix sort. The radix sort equivalent of "divide and conquer" is to reduce the input set into a list of sorted and unsorted ranges, and handles all remaining unsorted ranges together in each pass. BTW you can see an application for bitonic sort in [sorting doubles in SSE2 registers](http://mischasan.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/okay-one-more-poke-at-sse2-sorting-doubles/). HTH